# How to concatenate a file to multiple files?

Tags: bash, file

I want concatenate `text` to all the files in `dir`.
I use `for` to complete this job like the following code.
I want to know is there has a more concise code to do the same thing?

```
for fn in dir/*; do
  cat text >> $fn
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `text` is a file name, try:

```
tee -a dir/* <text >/dev/null
```

If `text` is actually some text that you want to append, then in bash:

```
tee -a dir/* <<<"text" >/dev/null
```

`tee` is a utility that reads from standard input and writes it to any number of files on its command line.  It also copies the standard input to standard out which is why `>/dev/null` is used above.  The `-a` option tells `tee` to append rather than overwrite.

#### Variation

As suggested by [kvantour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8344060/kvantour), it may be more clear to put the redirection for input at the beginning of the line:

```
<text tee -a dir/* >/dev/null
```

(In the above, `text` is assumed to be a filename)

Comment: What if there is a subdirectory in `dir`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell `tee` will not write to directories.  If `dir/*` were to include noe or more directories, all the files would be written to just like we want, while, for any directory on the command line, a message like `tee: dir/dir2: Is a directory` appears on stderr.

Answer (score 4):

There are problems with your code:

- If no files in `dir` exists, you will write `text` to a file named `*` literally.
- `$fn` expansion is unquoted!

I would:

```
find dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'cat text >> "$1"' _ {} \;
```

which I do not think is more concise.

Answer (score 3):

You can do them all concisely and in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel 'cat text >>' ::: dir/*
```